# for loop only accesses last object of array even though counter variable is incremented

Tags: java, arrays, object, for-loop, system.out

I have created 5 Box objects, placed them in an array named boxes and would like to iterate through them in order to print their information. The one array object that does get accessed is printed successfully so I know the methods are fine.

But my for loop seems to only access the very last object. The one with 3.14,99.1, and 26.7 as the arguments. It prints it 5 times so I know the conditional (x < boxes.length) is working properly. How can I successfully iterate through each object in the array?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoxTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {          
        Box[] boxes= new Box[5];

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a height: ");
        double height = stdin.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter a width: ");
        double width = stdin.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter a length: ");
        double length = stdin.nextDouble();


        Box first = new Box(width, length, height);
        boxes[0] = first;

        Box second = new Box();
        boxes[1] = second;

        Box third = new Box(2,3.5,5.75);
        boxes[2] = third;

        Box fourth = new Box(6.66,4.20,9.11);
        boxes[3] = fourth;

        Box fifth = new Box(3.14,99.1,26.7);
        boxes[4] = fifth;

        for (int x = 0; x < boxes.length; x++ ) {

            System.out.println(Box.toString(boxes[x]) + " Area: " +
                               Box.calculateArea(boxes[x]) + " Volume: " +
                               Box.calculateVolume(boxes[x]));

        }
```

}

Comment: You didn't include the Box class. Are the Box class members static? They shouldn't be. And `toString`, `calculateArea`, and `calculateVolume` shouldn't be static either.

Comment: @Eran Great catch

Comment: Yeah they are static.. how did you know?! and would changing them fix the problem? I had to turn it in 5 minutes ago I just turned in the version the printed the last object 5 times haha.

Comment: @Jason_Silva He knew because we've seen too many newbies overuse `static` and it fit the symptom of your problem. From Eran's comment, you should infer this: Your `Box` class should not use the `static` keyword *anywhere*. Not on fields. Not on methods.

Comment: @Andreas Can you please explain why declaring the method as static has this effect? I thought declaring it static just meant it could be called by other methods.

Comment: @Jason_Silva `static` fields (or members), methods means they don't belong to any object, it means these fields/methods belongs to class, and every instance of that class share these fields/methods. When you have constructed the fifth box, all boxes have their static fields to it's values, so all the boxes have the same values. In other words, these boxes does not have an individual "shape".

Comment: @Jason_Silva Declaring the *fields* as `static` has that effect. But, second part of Eran's comment is guidance telling you that your *methods* also shouldn't be `static`. If the methods aren't static, then you can call them the way they are supposed to be called, e.g. `boxes[x].calculateArea()` instead of `Box.calculateArea(boxes[x])`.

Answer (score -3):

Your Methods Should not be Static.
Change Box class to toString.
for (int x = 0; x < boxes.length; x++ ) {
    System.out.println(boxes[x]);

Comment: That has nothing to do with the actual problem, which is that the *fields* are `static`.